# VS 2015 "if" condition executing to wrong block

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2015

I have an `if`condition with `false` result executing like it was `true`.

Without break point:

[image]

With break point:

[image]

Comment: Are you sure that actual line is executed if you hit F10?

Comment: Are you sure you aren't watching two threads at the same time? Perhaps two calls that are happening at the same time...

Comment: Rebuild all to make sure there isn't old code running

Comment: @L-Three Yes, the actual line is executed

Comment: @xanatos It's only 1 thread, this code is called by a MVC controller.

Comment: @SamiKuhmonen I tried rebuild, but same result

Comment: Stupid idea that absolutely shouldn't change a thing, but....put curly braces around the line that shouldn't be executing. And maybe add a debugger assertion on that id value.

Comment: Any chance you have some unusual optimizations turned on? Given this is VS2015 and the Rosalyn compiler, makes me suspect some odd little edge case may be going on here that's really a bug...

Comment: Are you executing from Visual Studio, or attaching to a process? If attaching to a process, rebuild and also deploy the rebuilt executable and/or libraries.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In my experience, there are two common things that can cause this:

1. The DLL that is running does not correspond to the code you are viewing. This can be checked by making sure that Tools > Options > Debugging > "Require source files to exactly match the original version" is checked.
2. You have compiled in Release mode using optimized compiling and the compiler has reordered the code so it looks like that line of code is being executed, but it is really not (you can verify that this is happening by switching to Debug mode and trying again). This is typically the most common way I see this behavior when debugging.